# Ransack not rendering with turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, ransack

In the table below, ransack search works perfectly fine without turbolinks, but with it, the submit button works only after reloading the page.
There is a somewhat related issue opened [here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/334), but I did not find it helpful.
Is there a way to fix the search submit button, without refreshing the current page each time?

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th ID
      %th Name
  %tbody
    %tr
    = search_form_for @q, url: courses_path do |f|
      %th= f.text_field :id_eq
      %th= f.text_field :s_name_cont
      = f.submit "Search"
  %tbody
    - @courses.each do |course|
      %tr
        %td= course.id
        %td= course.s_name
```

My application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require moment
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1):

While not a great solution, it's *a* solution:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { 
  if($('#some_form_id').find('input[type=submit]').length <= 0) { 
    $('#some_form_id').prepend('<input type="submit" />');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, changing the order of elements in the table and putting the `= search_form_for` out of the table helped:

```
= search_form_for @q, url: courses_path do |f|
  = f.submit "Search"
  %table
    %thead
      %tr
        %th ID
        %th Name
    %tbody
      %tr
        %th= f.text_field :id_eq
        %th= f.text_field :s_name_cont
    %tbody
      - @courses.each do |course|
        %tr
          %td= course.id
          %td= course.s_name
```